# Get target length of *printf function family

Tags: c, malloc, printf

I need the target length of how many characters I will need in a `*printf` function. My scenario is a logging facility that should finally create a string (what happens to it is irrelevant, it must end in a `char *`).

I currently have this:

```
void log(char *format, ...)
{
    char *full_message, *message;
    FILE *nullfile;
    va_list args;

    va_start(args, format);
    nullfile = fopen("/dev/null", "w");
    message_len = vfprintf(nullfile, format, args) + 1;
    fclose(nullfile);
    va_end(args);

    va_start(args, format);
    message = malloc(message_len);
    vsnprintf(message, message_len, format, args);
    va_end(args);

    // now do something with the final message
}
```

That works like a charm, but it seems overly complicated. Is there an easier way? Something that makes more sense.

Additional detail: I finally format the string further and dump it into an OpenSSL `BIO`, so its not as easy as using `vfprinf`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A sane and reasonable simplification would be to use `vsnprintf()` instead of `vfprintf()`, since all you need is a `NULL` pointer and a buffer size of zero, instead of a file. Somewhat more elegant. (And don't worry, it's a common idiom in C to call functions like these ones twice: for the first time in order to figure out the buffer length, and for the second time, to actually get the job done.)

```
va_start(args, format);
int message_len = vsnprintf(NULL, 0, format, args) + 1;
va_end(args);
```

**Oh, and...**

```
void log(char *format, ...)
```

should be

```
void log(const char *format, ...)
```

Really.

Answer (score 2):

This is what snprintf is for:

```
void log(char *format, ...)
{
    char *message;
    va_list args;

    va_start(args, format);
    message_len = vsnprintf(0, 0, format, args) + 1;
    va_end(args);

    va_start(args, format);
    message = malloc(message_len);
    vsnprintf(message, message_len, format, args);
    va_end(args);

    // now do something with the final message
}
```